# Same text, style, browser, but different height on different screens

Tags: css

One identic webpage seems to be rendered differently on different DPI screens.
The font is same (google font), no media queries, but I have difference of 2,5 lines.
[image: Big screen]
[image: 13" notebook (1920x1080)]

And the client told, that he wants the text to **begin** & **end** at same height as the menu next to it.

If anyone would like to see it [here is is](http://dev.agereklama.cz/lokalita)

Any suggestions what to do?

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uaf6Lsc5/)

```
<section class="holder">
    <nav> <span class="selected">Popis</span>
 <span>Mapa</span>

    </nav>
    <div ng-if="selected.state=='popis'">
        <img src="http://dev.agereklama.cz/Images/Praha%209.png" class="filler" />
        <p>Do městského obvodu Prahy 9 a jeho části Prahy 14 patří také původně samostatná obec za tehdejší hranicí Velké Prahy jménem Kyje. Jméno obce Kyje (dříve Keje) je doloženo již k roku 1052 a je odvozeno od starého osobního jména Kyj , tj. "ves Kyjovy rodiny". V tomto období ves patřila pražskému arcibiskupství.</p>
        <p>Kyje se skládají ze sedmi místních čtvrtí, a to Staré Kyje, Jiráskova (původně Masarykova čtvrť), Aloisov, Lehovec, Nad rybníkem, Rajská Zahrada a Hutě.
            <br/>Kyje byly k Praze připojeny v roce 1968.</p>
        <p>V rezidenční čtvrti Hutě plné parků, zeleně a příjemných míst, jež je místně příslušná Praze 9 - Kyje, vzniká náš nový projekt <b>VILLA VICTORIA</b>.</p>
        <p>Nejbližší okolí projektu <b>VILLA VICTORIA</b> tvoří rodinné domy, zahrady, parky, dětská hřiště a základní občanská vybavenost. Veškeré vymoženosti velkoměsta, jako obchodní centrum, služby, městská doprava, metro jsou v docházkové vzdálenosti či jen pár minut vozem nebo autobusem ze zastávky poblíž domu.</p>
        <p>Potřebujete-li, snadno se napojíte na Vysočanskou radiálu, Pražský okruh, dálnici D11 a nebo rychlostní silnice R10. Místními komunikacemi se dostanete rychle na Černý Most, do Hloubětína nebo do Satalic. Čtvrtí projíždějí autobusy pražské MHD (linka 186 a 202). Na jih od Villa Victoria je situována stanice metra Rajská zahrada vzdálená jen 15 minut chůze. Do budoucna je plánována výstavba železniční zastávky v blízkosti Rajské zahrady a současně vznikne i pěší lávka, která zlepší propojení mezi čtvrtí Hutě a sídlištěm Černý Most.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

section nav {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

img.filler {
    float: right;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.holder {
    width: 621px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



section nav>span.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}

section nav>span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: post the css and html

Comment: There ain't much, is is just, it is acting wierd...

Comment: You are giving some size in pixel. The size of a pixel can change from screen to screen.

Comment: What is universal, then?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

Comment: So basicly none?... as all is relative to px?

Comment: I don't think there are any units that would solve the problem. What you could do is divide the right side to the top nav (the two links) and then the actual content, and make the nav stick to the top and the content to the bottom of the container.